# /dz/ and /z/ Is there really big difference?

Tags: pronunciation, consonant-clusters

I have difficulty distinguishing the two phonetic symbols. Roads, rose; needs, knees... Do these words sound very different to native speakers? How should I pronounce them?

Comment: The difference being that one has a d sound that requires pronounciation, and the other does not.

Comment: I believe that all English speakers are able to discern the difference. Perhaps your native language doesn't have a consonant cluster.

Comment: Yes, there is a difference. Try pronouncing "road" with the d on the end, then try to add an s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **/dz/** the tongue (almost) taps against the [alveolar ridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_ridge) (similar to **/d/**) before pronouncing the subsequent **/z/**. This does not happen with **/z/**, as a matter of course.

Pronounce repeatedly **/d/** followed by **/z/**. With each repetition reduce the distance between the two. Don't try to pronounce a perfect **/d/** before the **/z/** as the **/d/** is a reduced one and the **/z/** dominates. You got it if you not even need to move the tonge in order to pronounce both subsequent sounds. Then, the tongue is prepared for the pronunciation of **/z/** (by means of its very tip) and of **/d/** (by means of its upper front part). The **d** explosion happens between the alveolar ridge and the upper front part of the tongue and is followed directly by the **z** pronunciation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, **/dz/** and **/z/** sound very different to native speakers, and when pronounced properly are clearly distinguishable.

It is actually far more common for **/dz/** and **/ts/** to be confused by non-native speakers, but even these are distinct.

As to how they should be pronounced - you should pronounce them as per pronunciation guides! Some sounds in any language can pose problems for non-native speakers, but if you try your best, native speakers can more easily use wider context to make up for slight deviations in pronunciation.

Comment: (+1) Some minimal pairs for /ts/ and /dz/ are _totes/toads_, _boats/bodes_, _goats/goads_. These can indeed be difficult even for native speakers to distinguish aurally. Luckily I can't think of any pairs where the meanings are similar enough to present any potential for confusion, given context.

Comment: The consonant clusters at the end of the word "totes" and "toads" are normally indistinguishable. That's because final-word obstruents are usually devoiced (at least partially). The only difference that speakers can hear is the vowel length. The *GOAT* vowel in "toads" is just slightly longer. [This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/223160/the-pronunciation-of-ending-s/223308?r=SearchResults#223308) by Araucaria is very interesting.